# Laravel path is doubled with windows open

Tags: laravel, vue.js, response

I have changed the response.php as described in some page:

```
    $page = [
        'component' => $this->component,
        'props' => $props,
        //'url' => $request->getBaseUrl().$request->getRequestUri(),
        'url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
        'version' => $this->version,
    ];
```

like this, now I have a problem in opening a new tab. I have pdf to download and my controller is returning the file like this:

```
return $pdf->download($pdfname);
```

And in the vue:

```
window.open("/contract/generatePDF?id="+props.contract.id, '_blank');
```

the problem is the path is doubled: `/backend/public/contract/startHandover/contract/generatePDF?id=546` but not for other endpoints(for example this is working correctly: `form.post(route("transaction.store"));`) . The path should be like this  `/backend/public/contract/generatePDF?id=546`

Comment: If the path was doubled you'd expect two `/generatePDF` segments.  It's probably just relative to your current URL. Also, window.open and form.post aren't creating your URLs the same way... if it's a relative problem then try absolute URL